# Scraping ASP.net website using Scrapy login failure

Tags: python, asp.net, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to scrape data from a site that uses ASP.NET. When I’m not logged in, I can scrape all data that is freely available. However, for proprietary material I need to log in. 
When I call FormRequest.from_response(), I fail to login. Any Idea what I'm missing? Here is my spider:

```
def parse_login(self, response):

    vs = response.xpath('//*[@name="__VIEWSTATE"]/@value').extract_first()
    vsg = response.xpath('//*[@name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]/@value').extract_first()
    ev = response.xpath('//*[@name="__EVENTVALIDATION"]/@value').extract_first()
    return [scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response=response,method='POST',formdata={
                                                # '__EVENTTARGET':'',
                                                # '__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
                                                #'__VIEWSTATE':vs,
                                                'ctl00$cph_main$txt_email:':login_user,
                                                'ctl00$cph_main$txt_pass':login_password,
                                                #'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':vsg,
                                                #'__EVENTVALIDATION':'',
                                                },callback=self.start_crawl)]
```

Here is Form Data after “inspect”ing login page via “network tab”, POST method with 302 status code:

```
ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField: 

__EVENTTARGET: 

__EVENTARGUMENT: 

__VIEWSTATE: ‘VIEWSTATE_STRING’

__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR: C2EE9ABB

__EVENTVALIDATION: ‘EVENTVALIDATION_STRING’

ctl00$cph_main$txt_email: my_eml

ctl00$cph_main$txt_pass: my_pswrd

ctl00$cph_main$Button1: login
```